# having problem in shopping cart pricing rule magento

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have created shopping cart rules on my site. Let me explain in detail:

- My first rule is "Buy product A with 3 e-liquids and get 15 off" having highest priority.
- Second rule is "Buy product B with 1 e-liquids and get 10 off" having medium priority
- Third rule is "Buy 3 e-liquids and get 5 off" having low priority.

Now my basket has "Product A+ Product B + 4 e-liquids"

In this condition, all 3 rules are applying. All rules fulfill their condition. But I don't want it like this.

What I want is, in this condition only the first rule should apply and it should work like this:

1. Rule 1 have high priority so it will be apply on product A.
2. Now remaining product in the basket are product B and 1 e-liquids.
3. So second rule will be apply on remaining basket ("product B and 1 e-liquids") but condition for 2nd rule is not fulfill.

So, Only rule 1 will apply.

Answer (score 1):

So from what i can understand, you can stop you other rules from processing. Under shopping cart rules > `actions` tab you can find `Stop further Rules Processing`. This will allow your first rule to process and no other rules.

More info:

[Shopping cart recipes](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/shopping-cart-price-rule-recipes)

Comment: Thank you for your help.But exactly i don't want this. I Just want when first high priority rule is applied then second rule will be apply to the remaining products on which first rule doesn't work.